# A base of the kernel of a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-transformations

A base of the kernel of the linear transformation of $T: \mathbb{R}^3 → \mathbb{R}^3$, where $T (x, y, z) = (2x + y - 2z, x + z, x + y - 3z)$, is the set?

So.. I dont know how to calculate the base of the kernel....I know that the ker(T) is when T(x,y,z) = (0,0,0), but when i make 2x+y-2z = 0, x+z = 0.... and try to solve the system, i dont know how to find the base ... and the asnwer of the system does not make sense to me. is like any value of x,y,z drives to 0,0,0...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! What have you tried so far? Where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: What did you tried? Show some efforts.

Comment: @DiegoMath I dont know how to calculate the base of the kernel....I know that the ker(T) is when T(x,y,z) = (0,0,0), but when i make 2x+y-2z = 0, x+z = 0.... and try to solve the system, i dont know how to find the base ... and the asnwer of the system does not make sense to me. is like any value of x,y,z drives to 0,0,0...

Comment: @FELINTONETO Please include your comment in the question body.

Comment: @FELINTONETO, the solution $(0,0,0)$ is the famous trivial solution, but there exists another solutions.

Comment: @FELINTONETO Actually the trivial solution is always an element of the kernel since it is a linear subspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here some hints that lead you to the solution:

> 1. Compute the solution of the homogeneous system $\left\{\begin{aligned}2x+y-2z&=0\\x+z&=0\\x+y-3z&=0\end{aligned}\right..$
> 2. The solution is like $(a,b,c)t$, where $(a,b,c)$ is a particular solution (not the trivial solution!) and $t\in\mathbb{R}$ is a real parameter.
> 3. An basis can be $\mathcal{B}=\{(a,b,c)\}$.

Comment: So, when I try to solve the system... It anulates it self.. so i donw know how to get in (a,b,c)t form..

Comment: @FELINTONETO what method are you trying?

Comment: substitution method..

Comment: Hint: If you multiply the second by $-2$ and sum up to the first equation, after that multiply the second equation by $-1$ and sum uo to the third equantion, the system will be equivalent to $$\left\{\begin{aligned}y-4z&=0\\x+z&=0\\y-4z&=0\end{aligned}\right..$$ Do you can finish now?

Comment: Perfect! Is the solution i was trying to find... But, just to understand.. if i put in z(-1,4,1), z is like a eigenvalue and (-1,4,1) is an eigenvector?

Comment: @FELINTONETO, No, because $T(-1,4,1)\neq z(-1,4,1)$ for $z\neq0$.

Comment: Of course... eigenvalue and vector are for T(x,y,z) = k.(x,y,z)..Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: One way is to row-reduce the following  matrix: $\begin{pmatrix}2&1&1\\1&0&1\\-2&1&-3\end{pmatrix}$.   Then "back-substitute".

Get $\to\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&-1\\0&1&-1\end{pmatrix}\to\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&-1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Now back-substituting, we get $y=z$ and $x=-z$.  Thus $\{(-1,1,1)\}$ is a basis.